# externally loaded javascript won't execute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having trouble running javascript from an external file. Here's where it's included in the html:

```
<div id="article-author-list" class="article-author-list">
    <#list authorGroups as authorGroupItem>
        <@authorGroup item=authorGroupItem/>
    </#list>
    <script type="text/javascript">alert('Hello??');</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/article/truncateAuthors.js">    </script>
</div>
```

Whereas here's truncateAuthors.js:

```
alert('Found the script!!!');
$(window).load(function () {
    alert('Found the script.');
});
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert('Document is ready');
});
$(function(){
    alert('Running the script');
});
```

When the html is loaded, the only alert is 'Hello??' from the inline script. How can I get the external file to execute?

Comment: Please check file path.

Comment: Are you sure the js file is being loaded?  Open your browser dev tools (usually F12) and monitor the network traffic.  I suspect you'll see a 404.

Comment: If you use chrome (CTRL+SHIFT+J or F12), check the developer console for any errors, and post them here. It looks like some path problem as @ParthTrivedi pointed out.

Comment: @JamesThorpe beat me by 30 seconds...

Comment: Is jQuery included? Look at the network request on the server. Do you see a 404 or any errors?

Comment: @epascarello Even if it's not, the alert should fire before any errors appear.

Comment: jQuery is included. Looks like it is a 404. It's unusual, because my IDE can resolve the link just fine... Do I need to do something to make the file visible to the browser?

Answer (score 0):

Before call your javascript please add this
`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>` 
to your file it will work fine. this is jquery library file that we have to use when we are writting code in jquery

Comment: This link <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

I found it! The project was using requireJS and I needed to add it to the declaration. Thanks for all your answers :)